# bash: process list of files in chunks

Tags: bash, shell, batch-processing

**The setting:**

I have some hundred files, named something like `input0.dat`, `input1.dat`, ..., `input150.dat`, which I need to process using some command `cmd` (which basically merges the contents of all files). The `cmd` takes as first option the output filename and then a list of all input filenames:

```
./cmd output.dat input1.dat input2.dat [...] input150.dat
```

**The problem:**

The problem is that the script can only handle like 10 files or so due to memory issues (don't blame me for that). Thus, instead of using the `bash` wildcard extension like

```
./cmd output.dat *dat
```

I need to do something like

```
./cmd temp_output0.dat file0.dat file1.dat [...] file9.dat
[...]
./cmd temp_outputN.dat fileN0.dat fileN1.dat [...] fileN9.dat
```

Afterwards I can merge the temporary outputs.

```
./cmd output.dat output0.dat [...] outputN.dat
```

**How do I script this efficiently in `bash`?**

I tried, without success, e.g.

```
for filename in `echo *dat | xargs -n 3`; do [...]; done
```

The problem is that this again processes all files at once, because the output lines of `xargs` get concatenated.

**EDIT:** Note that I need to specify an output filename as first command line argument when calling `cmd`!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**edit** Without a pipe or process substitution - requires bash. This is able to deal with files with spaces in their names. Use a bash array and extract in slices:

```
i=0
infiles=(*dat)
opfiles=()
while ((${#infiles[@]})); do
    threefiles=("${infiles[@]:0:3}")
    echo ./cmd tmp_output$i.dat "${threefiles[@]}"
    opfiles+=("tmp_output$i.dat")
    ((i++))
    infiles=("${infiles[@]:3}")
done
echo ./cmd output.dat "${opfiles[@]}"
rm "${opfiles[@]}"
```

Using a fifo - this is *not* capable of dealing with spaces in filenames:

```
i=0
opfiles=
mkfifo /tmp/foo
echo *dat | xargs -n 3 >/tmp/foo&
while read threefiles; do
    ./cmd tmp_output$i.dat $threefiles
    opfiles="$opfiles tmp_output$i.dat"
    ((i++)) 
done </tmp/foo
rm -f /tmp/foo
wait
./cmd output.dat $opfiles
rm $opfiles
```

You need to use a fifo to keep the `i` variable value, as well as for the final concatenation set of files.

If you want, you can background the inside invocation of `./cmd`, put a `wait` before the last invocation of cmd:

```
i=0
opfiles=
mkfifo /tmp/foo
echo *dat | xargs -n 3 >/tmp/foo&
while read threefiles; do
    ./cmd tmp_output$i.dat $threefiles&
    opfiles="$opfiles tmp_output$i.dat"
    ((i++)) 
done </tmp/foo
rm -f /tmp/foo
wait
./cmd output.dat $opfiles
rm $opfiles
```

**update**
If you want to avoid using a fifo entirely, you can use process substitution to emulate it, so rewriting the first one as:

```
i=0
opfiles=()
while read threefiles; do
    ./cmd tmp_output$i.dat $threefiles
    opfiles+=("tmp_output$i.dat")
    ((i++)) 
done < <(echo *dat | xargs -n 3)
./cmd output.dat "${opfiles[@]}"
rm "${opfiles[@]}"
```

Again avoiding piping into the while, but reading from a redirection to keep the `opfiles` variable after the while loop.

Comment: Yes! That's what I've been looking for.  Thanks.

Comment: This is rather more convoluted than it really needs to be.  The temporary file can be avoided -- just pipe `xargs` to `while read`.  The background processing might be nice, but could also complicate things needlessly, depending on how heavy the job is, etc.

Comment: this doesn't work if the filenames have spaces in them

Comment: True, I've added an update that works with files with spaces in their names as well - it uses arrays, which is pretty much the only way to fly if you're trying to keep safe.

Answer (score 5):

Try the following, it should work for you:

```
echo *dat | xargs -n3 ./cmd output.dat
```

EDIT: In response to your comment:

```
for i in {0..9}; do
    echo file${i}*.dat | xargs -n3 ./cmd output${i}.dat
done
```

That would send no more than three files at a time to `./cmd`, while going over all file from `file00.dat` to `file99.dat`, and having 10 different output files, `output1.dat` to `output9.dat`.

Comment: I see, I added what I think could work for you. Is that what you meant?

Comment: No, actually, it does not quite do the right thing, because you're using the same output name multiple times for different input files.

Answer (score 3):

I know that this question was answered and accepted a long time ago, but I find that there is a more simple solution than those offered so far.

```
find -name '*.dat' | xargs -n3 | xargs -n3 your_command
```

For more fine grained control, or to manipulate your string further, use the following form (substitute bash to your liking):

```
find -name '*.dat' | xargs -n3 | xargs -n3 -I{} sh -c 'your_command {}'
```

To parallelize the output (say, on 2 threads):

```
find -name '*.dat' | xargs -n3 | xargs -P2 -n3 -I{} sh -c 'your_command {}'
```

NOTE: This will not work for files that have spaces in them.

Comment: What does piping it through `xargs` twice do, exactly?

Comment: @Walf the first xargs call creates the chunks and the second xargs call parallelizes the chunks

Comment: Isn't the first `xargs` redundant? Shouldn't setting both `-P` and `-n` on the final `xargs` already handle splitting into chunks and parallelising? Also, that is likely to fail on filenames with whitespace in them, especially with `-n` present. `-L` could be better, but one should almost always use `xargs -d $'\n' ...` to split arguments on newlines, or better use `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 ...` to delimit with null bytes.

Comment: I also found many way to deal execute a function of a chunk of file but I really struggle to make it work with files having space too… :(

Comment: This is sad that it’s not possible to use a placeholder, like with option -I of xargs, but with alongside option -L, this placeholder being then a place holder for multiple args.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using this quick solution I found from the `bash` manpage.  It looks like others exist too.  Unlike `xargs -n`, this should handle spaces in filenames properly.

```sh
ls *dat | while readarray -tn 10 tenfiles && ((${#tenfiles[@]}))
do
  cmd output.dat "${tenfiles[@]}"
done
```

Comment: Great solution - the docs for `readarray` can be found with `help mapfile`.

Answer (score 1):

**GNU Parallel** is excellent at *"chunking things up"* and generating input/output filenames and counters. This will take 3 files at a time (`-N3`) and generate an intermediate output file that is sequentially numbered and contains the merged contents. And it does it in parallel for you - making use of all those CPU cores that you paid Intel so handsomely for:

```
parallel -N3 cmd output.{#} {} ::: {1..150}.dat
```

To see it in action, use `--dry-run` option

```
parallel --dry-run -N3 cmd output.{#} {} ::: {1..150}.dat
```

**Sample Output**

```
cmd output.1 1.dat 2.dat 3.dat
cmd output.2 4.dat 5.dat 6.dat
cmd output.3 7.dat 8.dat 9.dat
cmd output.4 10.dat 11.dat 12.dat
cmd output.5 13.dat 14.dat 15.dat
cmd output.6 16.dat 17.dat 18.dat
cmd output.7 19.dat 20.dat 21.dat
...
...
cmd output.49 145.dat 146.dat 147.dat
cmd output.50 148.dat 149.dat 150.dat
```

Comment: I think this really is the best solution because it gives you easy access to the counter while chunking. Thats super important when setting the output file path.